# FF Firefox identifies errors. But how?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firebug

I posted at http://www.scriptiny.com/qa/2637/why-is-tinybox2-so-slow-at-my-website?show=2639#a2639 and asked why TinyBox2 was so slow at http://chesstao.com/about.php

Author wrote and said: ... That being said if you look at the net tab in Firebug as you click on the items you will notice a couple requests per load that never complete and around four elements that 404 on top of a relatively slow page, all of which will slow the operation down. I would start by cleaning that page up and resolving the issues I mentioned. If you are still having issues then let me know.

OK, I'm game. I booted FF and went to Tools / Web Developer / Firebug and selected the Net tab. And it's blank! Is the author telling me that the HTML has 404 errors (unlikely)? Or that the javascripts have 404 errors?

I want to "notice a couple requests per load that never complete" identify and fix them. How can I identify these requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At which stage of the load process did you open firebug?  If you opened it after the page had already loaded you won't see anything in the Net tab.

Try refreshing the browser page and see if this give you the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the page with the request tab open in firebug in order to see the requests coming in.